# Cannot find data from string using regex while string.find() works just fine

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, urllib

```
import re
import urllib
p = urllib.urlopen("http://sprunge.us/QZhU")
page = p.read()
pos = page.find("<h2><span>")
print page[pos:pos+48]
c = re.compile(r'<h2><span>(.*)</span>')
print c.match(page).group(1)
```

When I run it:

```
shadyabhi@archlinux $ python2 temp.py 
<h2><span>House.S08E02.HDTV.XviD-LOL.avi</span> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    print c.match(page).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
shadyabhi@archlinux $
```

If I can find a string using string.find then what is the problem when I use regex. I have tried looking http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto but no help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only matches **at the beginning of the string**. Use [`search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search), [`finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) or [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).

Also note that `*` is greedy. You might want to change your regex to `r'<h2><span>(.*?)</span>'`.

In summary, the following works for me:

```
import re
import urllib
p = urllib.urlopen("http://sprunge.us/QZhU")
page = p.read()
pos = page.find("<h2><span>")
print page[pos:pos+48]
c = re.compile(r'<h2><span>(.*?)</span>')
print c.search(page).group(1)
```

Comment: Does by beginning mean "till the first newline comes"? Also, please tell what happened when I add "?"? It matches zero or 1 repetition of previous RE. Whats previoud RE? Isn't the while string a RE?

Comment: @shadyabhi: No, it means that the first character of the string must be the first character of the match. Matches beginning at the second character and thereafter are not considered. On the words, for `match` to work, the HTML document must *begin* with `<h2><span>...`, not contain it somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Also, please tell what happened when I add "?"? It matches zero or 1 repetition of previous RE. Whats previous RE? Isn't the whole string a RE?

Comment: @shadyabhi: `*?` is a single operator. It matches as few characters as possible, whereas `*` matches as many as possible. See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax